# keep footer wrap always on the bottom?

Tags: html, sticky-footer

Can someone tell me how to keep a footer wrap always justified to the bottom of the browser?  thank you.

Erik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [this](http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/) might be what you're looking for.

Comment: Pretty sure that Ryan Fait technique has achieved legendary status. The amount of times I've seen the same technique used on a whole heap of websites and projects is astounding. Very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Which technique do you prefer? CSS? jQuery?

For the latter my advice is to use the [UI.Layout](http://layout.jquery-dev.net/) library which will rocks your webpages layouts

Comment: I feel like jQuery would be overkill for something so trivial. If it can be done using CSS, it should be.