# Make the footer stick at the bottom of the page

Tags: css, wordpress, footer, sticky-footer

Here is the site (made in Wordpress): http://milabalami.com
I want to have the footer stick at the bottom of the page. Any solutions in how I do this? I have already tried cssstickyfooter.com and xs4all.nl/~peterned/examples/csslayout1.html but none worked as I wanted. What happened was that the main body of the page overlapsed the footer.

I have been wrapping my head around this the past two days and Im lost. Is there anyone that can solve this puzzle?

Comment: Note that I couldnt hyperlink two links there because im a new member.

Comment: This question has been asked 100's of times in the past. Did you search for your question first? http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=footer%20stick%20bottom

Comment: @JMC Creative Yes I did. Please read my question again and you will see that I did try out those other solutions with no luck. Please dont accuse me of not doing my research when I clearly stated that I did.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3973771/keep-footer-wrap-always-on-the-bottom or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42294/how-do-you-get-the-footer-to-stay-at-the-bottom-of-a-web-page for example

Comment: @JMC Creative ive already seen both of those posts and tested them. No luck.

Comment: hmmm I could not understand your question because you said that you do not want to make footer at fixed position. So I think you are looking for something like this..... float:left for #container and top:100px; for #footer and top:-340px; for #flash. OR otherwise try position:absolute; bottom:0; for #footer and position:relative; for #wrapper OR insert a clear-float div above #footer..

Answer (score 1):

I've always used footerStickAlt, detailed here: http://www.themaninblue.com/writing/perspective/2005/08/29/

Answer (score 0):

try `position: fixed;` on the footer element. Is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Please, have a look on this:
http://www.hardcode.nl/archives_139/article_244-jquery-sticky-footer.htm#sticky_footer

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `z-index` in the style for your `footer`?
It'll make the `footer` come out front so the content doesn't overlap it.